# Populate TreeView with arbitrary depth from DataTable

Tags: c#, tree, .net-datatable

I have a DataTable with **id**, **parent**, **label** columns and want to populate a TreeView with it.

I'm new to c# and as far as I understand, there is no ready solution for it, unlike some other languages.

So I sorted the data hierarchically at DataTable level and wrote not a very pretty recursive method.

Is this a good solution or can it be greatly improved?

```
    using System.Data;

    public void Populate()
    {
        //data example
        var table = new DataTable();
        DataColumn column;
        DataRow row;
        column = new DataColumn(); column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32"); column.ColumnName = "id"; table.Columns.Add(column);
        column = new DataColumn(); column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32"); column.ColumnName = "parent"; table.Columns.Add(column);
        column = new DataColumn(); column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String"); column.ColumnName = "label"; table.Columns.Add(column);
        row = table.NewRow(); row["id"] = 1; row["parent"] = DBNull.Value; row["label"] = "root1"; table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table.NewRow(); row["id"] = 2; row["parent"] = 1; row["label"] = "child11"; table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table.NewRow(); row["id"] = 3; row["parent"] = 1; row["label"] = "child12"; table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table.NewRow(); row["id"] = 4; row["parent"] = DBNull.Value; row["label"] = "root2"; table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table.NewRow(); row["id"] = 5; row["parent"] = 4; row["label"] = "child21"; table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table.NewRow(); row["id"] = 6; row["parent"] = 5; row["label"] = "child211"; table.Rows.Add(row);
        // call method
        int i = 0;
        var result = new List<TreeNode>();
        var data = table.Rows;
        PopTree(ref data, DBNull.Value, ref i, ref result);
        treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(result.ToArray());
    }

    private void PopTree(ref DataRowCollection data, object parent, ref int i, ref List<TreeNode> result)
    {
        if (i >= data.Count || data[i]["parent"].ToString() != parent.ToString())
        {
            return;
        }
        var row = data[i];
        var children = new List<TreeNode>();
        i++;
        if (i < data.Count && row["id"].ToString() == data[i]["parent"].ToString())
        {
            PopTree(ref data, row["id"], ref i, ref children);
        }
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(row["label"].ToString(), children.ToArray());
        result.Add(node);
        PopTree(ref data, parent, ref i, ref result);
    }
```

Comment: *... or can it be greatly improved?*   That is a much more open question than you may realize.  Perhaps read this SO thread for starters:  [Tree Data Structure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66893/463206)

Answer (score 1):

Let me focus only on the `Populate` function in this post.

#### Defining Columns

You can define columns in a really concise way thanks to the `AddRange` method of the `DataColumnCollection` class

```
table.Columns.AddRange(new[] {
    new DataColumn("id", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("parent", typeof(int)), 
    new DataColumn("label", typeof(string)),
});
```

I would also advice to use `typeof` operator over `Type.GetType`

- since the former can give you compile time safety
- whereas the latter can fail at runtime in case of a typo for example.

#### Populating Rows with data

Unfortunately `DataRowCollection` does not define an `AddRange` method so, you have to add the rows one-by one. Here the preferred approach is to define the data separately from the `DataRow` population.

Here I have created an array of `ValueTuple`s to represent only the data.

```
var relationships = new (int Id, int? Parent, string Label)[] {
 (1, null, "root1"),
 (2, 1, "child11"),
 (3, 1, "child12"),
 (4, null, "root2"),
 (5, 4, "child21"),
 (6, 5, "child211"),
};
```

Finally here is a `foreach` to convert the data into a `DataRow` then add it to the `DataTable`

```
foreach (var relationship in relationships)
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row[0] = relationship.Id;
    if (relationship.Parent.HasValue)
        row[1] = relationship.Parent;
    else
        row[1] = DBNull.Value;
    row[2] = relationship.Label;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: It seems from the question text that the asker is interested in the `PopTree` algorithm and the `Populate` method is provided for the sake of having a working example.  The advice in this answer is sound, but it seems not to answer the question.

Comment: @phoog Yes that's right the question is more about the `PopTree`. But that `Populate` code was shouting for improvement :)

Comment: That is certainly true.